# Typicality of boundedness of entries of continued fraction representations

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, continued-fractions

> Is one of those claims about continued fractions true ?
>
> $1)$ Almost all real numbers have a continued fraction representation with a bounded sequence of entries.
>
> $2)$ Almost all real numbers have a continued fraction representation with an unbounded sequence of entries.

Intuitively I would expect that the unbounded sequence is the "typical" outcome. How can I determine the measure of both types of continued-fraction-sequences ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all real number have continued fractions expansion which is not only unbounded, but distribute according to the Gauss-Kuzmin measure. This follows from the fact that the Gauss map is ergodic. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kuzmin_distribution). This result should also appear in every textbook about ergodic theory and\or continued fractions (for example  "ergodic theory with a view towards Number Theory" by Einsiedler and Ward has a whole chapter on this).